# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "что"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Есть предложение:

> Каждый раз кажется что это навсегда.

Нужна ли тут запятая, мне вообще не ясно.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Это обычное сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП), на него распространяются соответствующие правила о постановке запятой в СПП.

Answer (score 2):

**Каждый раз кажется, что это навсегда.**

Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед союзом ЧТО.

Придаточное предложение эллиптического вида: это ― подлежащее, навсегда ― обстоятельство. Сказуемое в таких предложениях отсутствует (оно подразумевается, но не называется конкретно)